# How I add route rule from different controller or view or file by Urlmanager class in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

I want to add common url rules from a different files in **YII2**. How I array merge in return Urlmanager  array. I study about this

```
 getUrlManager()->addRules
```

but don't know I use it.

```
  'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => $paths['baseUrl'].'/backend',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you want to store url rules in another file?
Then you can just require file, like.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'baseUrl' => $paths['baseUrl'].'/backend',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => require('rules.php'),
    ],
```

And rules.php should be like

```
<?php
return array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        );
```

Comment: yes like that , but how i require it from different servers , any idea or solution

Comment: You can require by [url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).
Example #3 include through HTTP